# Preloading the images required by my PictureBox (.net)

Tags: .net, picturebox, image-preloader

I'm currently using the `ImageLocation` property of some `PictureBox`s on a form of mine.  The location is online but the images need to load before they are displayed.  The problem is, the images sometimes change to other pictures, but because of this, it doesn't display anything for a couple of seconds because the pictures haven't loaded.  Is it somehow possible to preload the specific image links during the application startup so that the images don't only load when they are set as the `ImageLocation` source?

I'm using VB.net but all .net answers are usable and appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to solve this by using the Image property instead of the ImageLocation property. During the application startup, you can load the images into variables, and when the form loads, you can assign each image variable to its respective PictureBox's Image property.